# Mysql select and date >= current date - 3 weeks

Tags: mysql, date

I have a select query that retrieves all entries that are 3 weeks old.

I want to know if there is an expression like `where date> Expr (CURDATE () - 3 WEEKS)` or if I must first make calculations of differences in my php script.

The format of my date is a `timestamp` like that : `2010-06-21 16:59:59`

Sincerely,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DATEDIFF()` function like so: `WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) = 21`.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the following line of code

```
where date>DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 3 WEEK);
```

Comment: More complicate than answer above, but It can help someone. Thank you =)

Comment: @Raphaël
This answer calculates the DATE_SUB() only once, while Anthony's answer does it for every line.  This answer seems a way better choice to me, since the performances difference may be significant in some cases..

Answer (score 2):

Use the actual input of timestamp is better,
as it allow query cache to take effect

From :- http://www.dangrossman.info/2007/04/26/mysql-tuning-disable-query-cache-on-frequently-updated-databases/

> Queries that contain non-deterministic functions aren’t cached. That includes CURDATE(), RAND(), or any other function where the output isn’t always the same.

From documentation :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html